# Tikzpicture [trim axis left,trim axis right] messing up legend matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider Stephan Pinnow's answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278530/how-i-can-customize-a-legend-on-pgfplots). When adding `[trim axis left,trim axis right]` to the `tikzpicture` environment (for reasons explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422976/set-bounding-box-of-pgfplots-diagram-relative-to-axes/422979#422979)), the legend matrix is destroyed for some strange reason:

Code:

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border={1.5cm 2pt 5mm 2pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % load `matrix' library so we can use the `matrix of nodes' feature
    \usetikzlibrary{
        matrix,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
        \begin{axis}[
            % just because it looks a bit better than the default
            cycle list name=exotic,
        ]
            \addplot {x};       \label{plot:line1}
            \addplot {x+4};     \label{plot:line2}

            \addplot {2*x};     \label{plot:line3}
            \addplot {2*x+4};   \label{plot:line4}

            \addplot {4*x};     \label{plot:line5}
            \addplot {4*x+4};   \label{plot:line6}

            % create a (dummy) coordinate where we want to place the legend
            %
            % (The matrix cannot be placed inside the `axis' environment
            %  directly, because then a catcode error is raised.
            %  I guess that this is caused by the `matrix of nodes' feature)
            \coordinate (legend) at (axis description cs:0.97,0.03);
        \end{axis}

        % create the legend matrix which is placed at the created (dummy) coordinate
        % and recall the plot specification using the `\ref' command
        %
        % adapt the style of that node to your needs
        % (e.g. if you like different spacings between the rows or columns
        %  or a fill color)
        \matrix [
            draw,
            matrix of nodes,
            anchor=south east,
        ] at (legend) {
            $ax$             & $ax+4$           &       \\
            \ref{plot:line1} & \ref{plot:line2} & $a=1$ \\
            \ref{plot:line3} & \ref{plot:line4} & $a=2$ \\
            \ref{plot:line5} & \ref{plot:line6} & $a=4$ \\
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `trim axis left`/`right` does is to set `trim left` and `trim right` to useful values, specifically the left/right side of the `axis`. The problem you're seeing probably occurs because every `\ref` to a labeled plot actually inserts a small `tikzpicture`, so presumably the trim settings are somehow inherited (this is guessing on my part). But those small pictures apply the `every crossref picture` style, so you can append `trim left=(current bounding box.west), trim right=(current bounding box.east)` to that style. This sets `trim left`/`trim right` to the the left/right edge of the small `tikzpicture`s, instead of the edges of the `axis`. Hence:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  trim axis left,trim axis right,
  /pgfplots/every crossref picture/.append style={
      trim left=(current bounding box.west),
      trim right=(current bounding box.east)
  }
]
```

[image]

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border={1.5cm 2pt 5mm 2pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % load `matrix' library so we can use the `matrix of nodes' feature
    \usetikzlibrary{
        matrix,backgrounds
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      trim axis left,trim axis right,
      /pgfplots/every crossref picture/.append style={
          trim left=(current bounding box.west),
          trim right=(current bounding box.east)
      }
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            % just because it looks a bit better than the default
            cycle list name=exotic,
        ]
            \addplot {x};       \label{plot:line1}
            \addplot {x+4};     \label{plot:line2}

            \addplot {2*x};     \label{plot:line3}
            \addplot {2*x+4};   \label{plot:line4}

            \addplot {4*x};     \label{plot:line5}
            \addplot {4*x+4};   \label{plot:line6}

            % create a (dummy) coordinate where we want to place the legend
            %
            % (The matrix cannot be placed inside the `axis' environment
            %  directly, because then a catcode error is raised.
            %  I guess that this is caused by the `matrix of nodes' feature)
            \coordinate (legend) at (axis description cs:0.97,0.03);
        \end{axis}

        % create the legend matrix which is placed at the created (dummy) coordinate
        % and recall the plot specification using the `\ref' command
        %
        % adapt the style of that node to your needs
        % (e.g. if you like different spacings between the rows or columns
        %  or a fill color)
        \matrix [
            draw,
            matrix of nodes,
            anchor=south east,
        ] at (legend) {
            $ax$             & $ax+4$           &       \\
            \ref{plot:line1} & \ref{plot:line2} & $a=1$ \\
            \ref{plot:line3} & \ref{plot:line4} & $a=2$ \\
            \ref{plot:line5} & \ref{plot:line6} & $a=4$ \\
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice find! The column headers `ax` and `ax+4` are off center, however.

Comment: @Christoph90 Sorry, I'd misunderstood `trim right` a bit, the updated version works better.