# pgfplots: trim axis breaks legend positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, legend, groupplots

I have a figure that should be centered and contain three plots.
One at the top, one at the bottom-left and one at the bottom-right.
I used one `tikzpicture` with a regular `begin{axis}` for the top plot and a `begin{groupplot}` for the bottom plots. The legend for the bottom plots should be centered above the two bottom plots / below the upper plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left, trim axis right, trim axis group left, trim axis group right]
    \begin{axis}[%
        name=plota,
        height=0.35\textwidth,
        legend style={
            anchor=south,
            at={(current bounding box.north-|current axis.north)},
            legend columns=2
        },
        ybar,
        x=25mm,
        ylabel={ylabel}
    ]
        \addplot[] coordinates { (0, 1) (1,2) (2,4) (3,8) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (0, 1) (1,3) (2,9) (3,27) };
        \addlegendentry{2}
        \addlegendentry{3}
    \end{axis}
    \node[text width=.45\linewidth,align=center,anchor=north](subfiga) at (plota.below south) {subfigure text a};
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1, group name=mygroup},
        height=.375\linewidth,
        log basis x={2},
        xlabel={Width (bytes)},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[
        name=plotb,
        at={(plota.below south west|-subfiga.south west)},
        yshift=-8mm,
        anchor=north west,
        legend to name={legend2},
        ylabel={ylabel}
    ]
        \addlegendentry{3}
        \addlegendentry{4}
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,2) (4,5) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,5) (4,7) };
    \nextgroupplot[
        name=plotc,
        at={(plota.below south east|-subfiga.south east)},
        anchor=north east,
        yticklabel pos=upper,
        yshift=-8mm,
    ]
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,3) (4,2) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,2) (4,3) };
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (plotb.above north west)-- coordinate(legendpos) (plotc.above north east);
    \node[align=center,anchor=south](legend) at (legendpos) {\ref{legend2}};

    \node[text width=.45\linewidth,align=center,anchor=north] at
        (plotb.below south) {subfigure text b};
    \node[text width=.45\linewidth,align=center,anchor=north] at
        (plotc.below south) {subfigure text c};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

The figure in itself basically works (but the axis is not centered with respect to the page), as long as I don't specify any of the `trim axis` options. If I specify all of them, the picture is centered, but the legend is off. If I specify just `trim axis left` and `trim axis right`, all hell breaks loose (i.e. the whole picture is off-center and the legend is off):

[image: tikz picture with trim axis options]

(ignore the legend overlapping the "subfigure a" text, I will resolve that with a `yshift`)

Plus, I get the following error that I don't understand, regardless of the `axis trim` options specified.

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named mygroup c1r1 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.54        ]
```

**Edit:** Using `alias` instead of `name` fixes this warning (thanks to user marmot). Is `alias` documented anywhere?

**Edit:** [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422994/tikzpicture-trim-axis-left-trim-axis-right-messing-up-legend-matrix) question seems related, although I wasn't able to implement the answer for the problem at hand.

Comment: `<pre><code>` seems broken. I edited the question to use space-indentation to format the code now.

Comment: The only occurences of `trim` I find in your code are in `%[trim axis left, trim axis right, trim axis group left, trim axis group right]`, which is commented out. On the other hand, you state that "It basically works, as long as I don't specify any of the trim axis options.". What do I have to do to get no errors?

Comment: It basically works means that it works as expected (minus the error message). I want the axis of the upper plot to be centered to the page. So I tried the axis trim options. And they seem to mess things up for me.

Answer (score 1):

This produces something in which the legend is positioned where I think you want to have it. I didn't touch the `trim`s because I do not understand what you want to do with them. What I did is:

1. Replaced `name=plotb` and `name=plotc` to `alias=plotb` and `alias=plotc` to get rid of the error message `! Package pgf Error: No shape named mygroup c1r1 is known.`
2. Added `midway` to the `legendpos` coordinate to have the legend in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left, trim axis right, trim axis group left, trim axis group right]
    \begin{axis}[%
        name=plota,
        height=0.35\textwidth,
        legend style={
            anchor=south,
            at={(current bounding box.north-|current axis.north)},
            legend columns=2
        },
        ybar,
        x=25mm,
        ylabel={ylabel}
    ]
        \addplot[] coordinates { (0, 1) (1,2) (2,4) (3,8) };
        \addlegendentry{2}
        \addplot[] coordinates { (0, 1) (1,3) (2,9) (3,27) };
        \addlegendentry{3}
    \end{axis}
    \node[text width=.45\linewidth,align=center,anchor=north](subfiga) at (plota.below south) {subfigure text a};
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1, group name=mygroup},
        height=.375\linewidth,
        log basis x={2},
        xlabel={Width (bytes)},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[
        alias=plotb,
        at={(plota.below south west|-subfiga.south west)},
        yshift=-12mm,
        anchor=north west,
        legend to name={legend2},
        ylabel={ylabel}
    ]
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,2) (4,5) };
        \addlegendentry{3}
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,5) (4,7) };
        \addlegendentry{4}
    \nextgroupplot[
        alias=plotc,
        at={(plota.below south east|-subfiga.south east)},
        anchor=north east,
        yticklabel pos=upper,
        yshift=-12mm,
    ]
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,3) (4,2) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (2,2) (4,3) };
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (plotb.above north west)-- (plotc.above north east) 
    coordinate[midway](legendpos) ;
    \node[align=center,anchor=south](legend) at (legendpos) {\ref{legend2}};

    \node[text width=.45\linewidth,align=center,anchor=north] at
        (plotb.below south) {subfigure text b};
    \node[text width=.45\linewidth,align=center,anchor=north] at
        (plotc.below south) {subfigure text c};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without the `trim axis` options, the plot itself is not centered on the page, it's bounding box (including e.g. yticks) is. I need the plot to be centered. The legend is only not centered with the `trim axis` options. I can confirm that using `alias` instead of `name` gets rid of the error message

Comment: @apriori Sorry, was offline. I see that you answered your own question, and deleted your answer. To answer your question contained in your answer: Yes, if you use `legend to name`, a self-contained picture will be created that can be used outside the current Ti*k*Z picture. Whether or not it is *always* safe to use it inside the *node* of another Ti*k*Z picture, I do not know by heart, but this is something that can be found out by looking at the source code. (You want to avoid nesting `tikzpicture` environments.)

Comment: Although starting a new `tikzpicture` worked at first, porting the MWE back to my actual document shifted them to the right (without an overfull hbox warning). I'm currently looking into that.

Comment: Well, it is hard to respond to that because I do not know what you concretely tried. (Sometimes one can use the `\centerline` primitive in such cases.)

Comment: The original question is still valid. I suspect that using `trim axis group left` and `trim axis group right` together with groupplots and a shared legend is just broken.

Comment: @apriori What is wrong with two separate tikzpictures?

Comment: When I tried two separate `tikzpictures`, I used `trim axis left` / `trim axis right` on the upper one and `trim axis group left` / `trim axis group right` on the lower one. The lower one still had the botched legend location.