# pgfplots: set effective width of figure if no label given

Tags: pgfplots, floats, tikzscale

How to ensure that the set width of `pgfplot` figure is correctly applied in case I do not have a label?

Please consider the example below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,calc,filecontents,tikzscale}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \begin{axis}[width=120pt,height=3cm]%
        \addplot[domain=-3:3] {sin(deg(x))};%
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test-label.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[width=120pt,height=3cm,ylabel=ylabel]%
    \addplot[domain=-3:3] {sin(deg(x))};%
    \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents*}

\def\mymacro{\input{test.tikz}}
\def\mymacrolabel{\input{test-label.tikz}}

\def\mymacroscaleonlyaxis{\includegraphics[width=120pt,height=3cm]{test.tikz}}
\def\mymacrolabelscaleonlyaxis{\includegraphics[width=120pt,height=3cm]{test-label.tikz}}

\newlength{\test}
\begin{document}
    \mymacro%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacro}%

    \the\test

    \mymacrolabel%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacrolabel}%

    \the\test

    \mymacroscaleonlyaxis%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacroscaleonlyaxis}%

    \the\test

    \mymacrolabelscaleonlyaxis%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacrolabelscaleonlyaxis}%

    \the\test
\end{document}
```

The cases where a ylabel is set, are scaled almost correctly (ca. 118pt instead of the desired 120pt).
But the figures without label are not scaled correctly in either case.
How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422979/24974 does not address your question?

Comment: @erik thanks for the pointer, when adding this to the code above, it removes whitespace around the (non-labeled) figure, but the width is then just approx. 75pt and not the desired 120pt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `trim axis left` (applied to the `tikzpicture`) with `scale only axis` (applied to the `axis`). If you only trim the axis, `pgfplots` will still allocate 45pt of space for tick marks and axis labels. If you only scale the axis, the axis decorations will add to the overall width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,calc,filecontents,tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \begin{axis}[width=120pt,height=3cm]%
        \addplot[domain=-3:3] {sin(deg(x))};%
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test-label.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[width=120pt,height=3cm,ylabel=ylabel]%
    \addplot[domain=-3:3] {sin(deg(x))};%
    \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.tikz.scaled}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]%
        \begin{axis}[width=120pt,height=3cm,scale only axis]%
        \addplot[domain=-3:3] {sin(deg(x))};%
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test-label.tikz.scaled}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]%
    \begin{axis}[width=120pt,height=3cm,ylabel=ylabel,scale only axis]%
    \addplot[domain=-3:3] {sin(deg(x))};%
    \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents*}

\def\mymacro{\input{test.tikz}}
\def\mymacrolabel{\input{test-label.tikz}}
\def\mymacroscaleonlyaxis{\input{test.tikz.scaled}}
\def\mymacrolabelscaleonlyaxis{\input{test-label.tikz.scaled}}

\newlength{\test}
\begin{document}
    \mymacro%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacro}\quad\the\test

    \mymacrolabel%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacrolabel}\quad\the\test

    \mymacroscaleonlyaxis%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacroscaleonlyaxis}\quad\the\test

    \mymacrolabelscaleonlyaxis%
    \settowidth{\test}{\mymacrolabelscaleonlyaxis}\quad\the\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't work for me when I tried after your first comment, because I used `tikzscale`'s overloaded `\includegraphics`.